# Matlab crashing on passing large array to Mex file

Tags: matlab, eigen, mex

I am trying to write a wrapper for the LibIGL Normal functions. But so far I have managed to crash Matlab everytime I call the mex function with a large array. So I went back to try write a function that just returns one of the inputs as the output. The output works, but only if it is a small array. When I try to pass a large array (like 53490x3), Matlab crashes.

I looked at the other questions open, and tried the solutions, but the problem persists.

My code is as follows:

```
#include <mex.h>
#include <igl\per_vertex_normals.h>

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]) {
    using namespace Eigen;

    int row = mxGetM(prhs[0]);
    int col = mxGetN(prhs[0]);
    int row2 = mxGetM(prhs[1]);
    int col2 = mxGetN(prhs[1]);

    int outRow = row;
    int outCol = col;

    Map<MatrixXd> V(mxGetPr(prhs[0]), row, col);
    Map<MatrixXd> F(mxGetPr(prhs[1]), row2, col2);
    if (nrhs != 2)
    {
        mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("MATLAB:mexcpp:nargin", "vertex normal function requires 2 inputs, the vertices and the faces to calculate upon.");
    }

    mwSize rows = V.rows();
    mwSize cols = V.cols();
    plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(rows, cols, mxREAL);
    Map<MatrixXd> map(mxGetPr(plhs[0]), rows, cols);
    map = V;
    return;
}
```

From my time that I spent with it, seems like crash happens when I am trying to access the V matrix to fill up the output. So it is some kind of invalid memory access (which is what the error says) that is happening. But I am not sure about how to get this working. What I would ideally want is to take the two matrix as input and calculate a result which would be another Eigen matrix and return that as the output.

Comment: To check if reading `V` or writing `map` is the problem, could you check `map.setOnes()` instead of `map = V`?

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

1. You might be overflowing `row`, `col`, `row2`, `col2`. Change them from `int` to `mwSize`. Unlikely to be a problem, but it will be machine dependent you don't mention your setup. You can check `limits.h` for `INT_MAX` which is normally plenty, but `mwSize` is safest. Output them with `mexPrintf` to make sure they are what you expect.
2. You might be out of memory. Check that `plhs[0]` is not `NULL`. Should not be a problem for `53490x3`.

Comment: 1. I changes it, but that didn't help, as expected. But good tip. Will keep that in mind. I am developing on a Windows machine, but will be running on a headless server that is running Linux.

2. I read about the NULL problem, but the thing is, if the mxCreateDoubleMatrix encounters a NULL, it returns control to MATLAB without running any further, so I should just get back to MATLAB, instead of it crashing. (As per the documentation)